# Android Studio AVD screen size and position

Tags: android, screen, android-virtual-device

I have a problem with Android Studio AVD as You can see on the image below: 
[AVD screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jpvJ0.png)
I am using Android Studio 2.3.1 up to date in Fedora Linux.
No matter if I change the resolution, screen size, phone type of the AVD it looks the same as in the image.
How can I fix it?
Thank You!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm struggling with similar problem right now. In my case... I've created the AVD from a command line for example *avdmanager --verbose create avd --force --name myEmulator--device "4in WVGA (Nexus S)" --package "system-images;android-23;google_apis;x86" --tag "google_apis" --abi "x86"* and then if you want to run newly created AVD emulator you should type the command 'emulator -avd myEmulator (and optional arguments)'. Maybe it was an issue with a path to system image.

Comment: It was helpfull! With the command below I managed to create a normally working AVD: avdmanager --verbose create avd --force --name myEmulator --device 16  --package "system-images;android-21;google_apis;x86_64" --tag "google_apis"